# smart assignment in 2D numpy array based on numpy 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array and I want to turn it to -1\1 values based on the following logic:

a. find the argmax() of each row

b. based on that 1D array (a) assign the values it contain the value 1

c. based on the negation of this 1D array assign the value -1

Example:

```
arr2D = np.random.randint(10,size=(3,3))
idx = np.argmax(arr2D, axis=1)

arr2D = [[5 4 1]
         [0 9 4]
         [4 2 6]]
idx = [0 1 2]

arr2D[idx] = 1
arr2D[~idx] = -1
```

what I get is this:

```
arr2D = [[-1 -1 -1]
         [-1 -1 -1]
         [-1 -1 -1]]
```

while I wanted:

```
arr2D = [[1 -1 -1]
         [-1 1 -1]
         [-1 -1 1]]
```

appreciate some help,
Thanks

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, did the trick!!
ive tried the second option, seemed most elegant for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Create a mask with those `argmax` -

```
mask = idx[:,None] == np.arange(arr2D.shape[1])
```

Then, use those indices and then use it to create those 1s and -1s array -

```
out = 2*mask-1
```

Alternatively, we could use `np.where` -

```
out = np.where(mask,1,-1)
```

**Approach #2**

Another way to create the mask would be -

```
mask = np.zeros(arr2D.shape, dtype=bool)
mask[np.arange(len(idx)),idx] = 1
```

Then, get `out` using one of the methods as listed in approach #1.

**Approach #3**

One more way would be like so -

```
out = np.full(arr2D.shape, -1)
out[np.arange(len(idx)),idx] = 1
```

Alternatively, we could use `np.put_along_axis` for the assignment -

```
np.put_along_axis(out,idx[:,None],1,axis=1)
```